# reading file with float values

Tags: c, file

I have a question reading a txt file containing float value.
I have seen some tutorials about reading txt files and all of them soo far are either using fgetc or fgets to read the content of files. I was looking for some similar function for float as the contents of my file is float. Is there a some way to read file containing float or i use these functions to break for flaot and read each as a character and then print that value  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are reading from just one text file, you may use I/O redirection.

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main() {
        float a;
        scanf("%f", &a);
        return 0;
    }
```

If your executable file name is say abc.exe or simply abc,
run as:

```
abc < in.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Read each line using [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), then depending on how the lines are formatted you could use [`sscanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) to parse the values, or [`strtod()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtod).

Comment: I changed `scanf()` to `sscanf()` which makes more sense when the line is already in a string.

Answer (score 1):

Use `fscanf` like this

```
fscanf(myfile,"%f",&myfloat);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`fscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float var;
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("input","r");
    fscanf(file, "%f", &var);
    printf("the value is %f\n",var);
    fclose(file);
    exit(0);
}
```

`fscanf` takes two initial parameters, a pointer to a `FILE` structure and a string format just like that of `printf`.
Then you can add other parameters, which will be *pointers* to the variables you are reading.
It will return the number of items successfully read.

There are other ways. If your input file has a nontrivial structure, you could try parsing it with some tools like [flex](https://github.com/westes/flex/) and [bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/). Flex is a tokenizer: it will help you read items from a file, splitting them (strings, numbers, identifiers, special symbols -- in any way you specify). Bison is a parser generator: you describe a grammar of tokens, and it will generate a parser for you.